# I want to copy the rows from one data frame to a new data frame, based on matching numbers?

Tags: r

```
new.df <- as.data.frame(match(unique_numbers$ID, MASTERFILE$ID))
```

I have a few million rows in a data frame called MASTERFILE. It contains a column "ID" with a bunch of integers. I have another data frame called "unique_numbers" which has a similar integer column "ID" with numbers in it.

I want to match the two "ID" columns from the different data frames so that the IDs that match in the MASTERFILE, will be copied to the new data frame "new.df".

The above command seems to work, but I'm afraid it only goes through each number ones, and the MASTERFILE may have the same ID written multiple times in different rows which I think it doesn't pick up!

Comment: are the lengths the same per ID, 10 matches per unique_numbers to to 10 matches masterfile ID as example?

Comment: Hello Andrew. No, the MASTERFILE contains a few million rows, each row with an ID in the ID column. Some rows may have the same ID though. The unique_numbers data frame only contains a couple of IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `%in%`

```
new.df <- MASTERFILE[MASTERFILE$ID %in% unique_numbers$ID, ];
```

Or if you want `new.df` to only contain the `ID` column:

```
new.df <- MASTERFILE[MASTERFILE$ID %in% unique_numbers$ID, "ID"];
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. Can you explain to me what the semicolon at the end means?

Comment: @Woels You can omit the semicolon; it's personal habit/preference; you only need a semicolon if you have multiple statements in one line (which is usually bad practice), e.g. `x <- 2; x + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see with no example (appreciate its millions of rows) even sample data would be good.

This may work?

```
# dummy data different ID lengths
unique_numbers <- rep(1:1000,each=10)
master_id <- rep(1:2000,each=20)
# subset the ones that match
new.df <- subset(master_id , master_id %in% unique_numbers)
```

or to your specific case:

```
new.df <- subset(MASTERFILE$ID, MASTERFILE$ID %in% unique_numbers$ID)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to dig deeper into the %in% function, seems to be quite useful!